# Passing filtering functions to Where() in LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to write a set of filtering functions that can be chained together to progressively filter a data set. What's tricky about this is that I want to be able to define the filters in a different context from that in which they'll be used. I've gotten as far as being able to pass a very basic function to the Where() clause in a LINQ statement:

filters file:

```
Func<item, bool> returnTrue = (i) => true;
```

repository file:

```
public IQueryable<item> getItems()
{
    return DataContext.Items.Where(returnTrue);
}
```

This works. However, as soon as I try to use more complicated logic, the trouble begins:

filters file:

```
Func<item, bool> isAssignedToUser = (i) => i.assignedUserId == userId;
```

repository file:

```
public IQueryable<item> getItemsAssignedToUser(int userId)
{
    return DataContext.Items.Where(isAssignedToUser);
}
```

This won't even build because userId isn't in the same scope as isAssignedToUser(). I've also tried declaring a function that takes the userId as a parameter:

```
Func<item, int, bool> isAssignedToUser = (i, userId) => i.assignedUserId == userId;
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't fit the function signature that Where() is expecting:

```
Func<item, bool>
```

There must be a way to do this, but I'm at a loss for how. I don't feel like I'm explaining this very well, but hopefully you get the gist.

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare your functions as pure standalone functions.  You can use an inline lambda:

```
public IQueryable<item> getItemsAssignedToUser(int userId)
{
    return DataContext.Items.Where(i => i.assignedUserId == userId);
}
```

The official documentation for lambdas is [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), but you might find easier-to-read results searching on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the wonders of [closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) the userId is already in the scope if you use an inline anonymous function in your Where clause.  This means that when you have an anonymous function in a method, variables within the method are available to the anonymous function even though they seem to be "outside."

```
public IQueryable<item> getItemsAssignedToUser(int userId)
{
    return DataContext.Items.Where( i => i.assignedUserId == userId);
}
```

You also could have created the Func isAssignedToUser inside the method getItemsAssignedToUser and passed it to the Where clause like this, but it would be unnecessary:

```
public IQueryable<item> getItemsAssignedToUser(int userId)
{
    Func<item, bool> isAssignedToUser = (i) => 
    {
        return i.assignedUserId == userId; 
    };

    return DataContext.Items.Where(isAssignedToUser);
}
```